# How to trim the result of an AD search?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using a search in AD using the code below:

```
Clear-Host
$Dept=Read-Host "Enter the desired department"
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Department=*$Dept*))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll() | Export-Csv H:\TEST\EXPORTtestNEW2222.csv
```

The results are in the following format:

```
#TYPE System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult 
Path    Properties
LDAP://CN=BECALI Gigi (SALES),OU=Users_NOAP,OU=SALES,OU=DGs,DC=net2,DC=cec,DC=fr,DC=int System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection
LDAP://CN=BRANESCU Mimi(SALES),OU=Users_NOAP,OU=SALES,OU=DGs,DC=net2,DC=cec,DC=eu,DC=int    System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection
LDAP://CN=BAU Cucu (SALES),OU=A2-testusersettings,OU=Users_NOAP,OU=SALES,OU=DGs,DC=net2,DC=cec,DC=eu,DC=int System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection
```

I need to "cut out" the part with "LDAP://" and the Properties part entirely (I don't need the `System.DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection` at all) and to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$objSearcher.FindAll() | export-csv H:\TEST\EXPORTtestNEW2222.csv
```

you can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to select and manipulate exactly the properties you want:

```
$objSearcher.FindAll() | Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression = {$_.Path.Substring(7)}} |Export-Csv H:\TEST\EXPORTtestNEW2222.csv
```

Here, we create a new property called `Path` and as its value take the existing `Path` property, but with the first 7 characters removed using `Substring()`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking after. It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could expand the `Path` property and remove the `LDAP://` prefix from the values. Also, don't export the results to a file if you want it in a variable.

```
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll() | Select-Object -Expand Path |
              ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^LDAP://' }
```

However, a much simpler approach would be to use the [`Get-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee617241.aspx) cmdlet from the `ActiveDirectory` module:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Dept = Read-Host "Enter the desired department"
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Department=*$Dept*))"

$colResults = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $strFilter |
              Select-Object -Expand DistinguishedName
```

Comment: Thank you to you too! I wish I could give you some points or something. I can only chose one answer with the green check mark, but clearly your approach is much simpler than mine